# Why explicit initialization list is more likely to failure?

Tags: c++

In the book *"Inside the C++ object model"*, the author says that:

> There are three drawbacks of an explicit initialization list:
>
> 1. It can be used only if all the class members are public.
> 2. It can specify only constant expressions (those able to be evaluated at compile time).
>
> **3. Because it is not applied automatically by the compiler, the likelihood of failure to initialize an object is significantly heightened.**

I don't know why the explicit initialization list is more likely to failure. And what is the meaning of "applied automatically by the compiler"?

Are there some examples to prove this point of view.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: _'I don't know why the explicit initialization list is more likely to failure'_ To be honest, I don't know either?!? Initialization policies are well defined for the current standards, and I cannot see any drawbacks in using _'explicit initialization lists'_. May be your book isn't a that good resource, or you missed some specific context.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ well the book was written in 1996 so a lot of the content is not going to applicable anymore.

Comment: Can you give author + page (or chapter/section) in your question please

Comment: @quantdev The book is "Inside the C++ object model" by Lippman, at chapter 5.1

Comment: 1996, wow. So it's a book about C++ before the first ISO standard. Yeah, I can see how things can change since then.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Agreed. This book may be a little bit too old and out of date. But I can't find some other book about this article.

Comment: @chris the `Deisng and Evolution of C++` is from 1994 but I feel like it has aged better, although it is also clearly very out of date.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, Yeah, there are those programming pearls (hint hint) that come along every once in a while and stay with us for ages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the example of an explicit initialization list in Lipmann's book.

```
Point1 local1 = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
```

I *think* the point he's trying to make is that you must remember to use the explicit initialization! In other words they're not a replacement for constructors. If you forget to use the list...

```
Point local2;
```

... then you have "failed to initialize the object". It's not that the initialization list can fail in any way, simply that you can fail to remember to use it.

Compare with a constructor

```
Point::Point (int x=0, int y=0, int z=0) : x(x), y(y) z(z) {};
```

You can now do both, and still get well defined results.

```
 Point local3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
 Point local4; // uses default values of 0,0,0
```

Comment: And is it a good habit to avoid using POD in C++ programming? Although POD may have a better performance.

Comment: @Wizmann, I really wouldn't be worried about any performance difference in nearly all cases. Anyway, a class can still have a lot and be a POD. The only requirements that conflict with this question is that it needs a trivial default constructor and POD data members. Anyway, see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec7100fcc3d8fb69

Comment: @chris But you still have to worry about the undefined value of the object if you forget to create it without the initialization list.

Comment: @Wizmann, Yes, you will, which is why the trivial default constructor requirement conflicts with the question.